# How to git bisect where bad commit is ancestor of good commit / find the fix commit?

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

1. A bug was reported long ago at commit `0badcommit` in the project and it went unnoticed.
2. When cleaning up tickets recently, this ticket was found but the issue no longer exists on the latest `main` branch.

I want to find which commit led to fixing of this particular issue. But, `git bisect` won't let me do it because the bad commit is ancestor of the good commit.
I get

```
Some good revs are not ancestors of the bad rev.
git bisect cannot work properly in this case.
Maybe you mistook good and bad revs?
```

Is there a way to reverse the bisect logic? Something else I can do to find out what commit accidentally fixed this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the great suggestion in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75407777/3715736, we can define our own good and bad "terms" with `git bisect` which makes it easier to retain the correct context.

For example, in order to define good as bad and bad as good (which gives me brainfreeze after a while), we can do

```
git bisect start --term-good mybad --term-bad mygood
```

and then, later on,

```
git bisect mybad 0c5c211ba # for our bad but really a good commit
git bisect mygood d04eb09ab # for our good but really a bad commit
```

**Edit (The correct answer):**
Actually, after digging manpage a bit more, the correct command for the kind of problem I'm trying to solve is to use `git bisect old` and `git bisect new`. These commands will tell you which commit introduced the fix instead of which commit broke things.

From the manpage:

> Sometimes you are not looking for the commit that introduced a breakage, but rather for a
> commit that caused a change between some other "old" state and "new" state. For example,
> you might be looking for the commit that introduced a particular fix. Or you might be
> looking for the first commit in which the source-code filenames were finally all converted
> to your company’s naming standard. Or whatever.
>
> In such cases it can be very confusing to use the terms "good" and "bad" to refer to "the
> state before the change" and "the state after the change". So instead, you can use the
> terms "old" and "new", respectively, in place of "good" and "bad". (But note that you
> cannot mix "good" and "bad" with "old" and "new" in a single session.)
>
> In this more general usage, you provide git bisect with a "new" commit that has some
> property and an "old" commit that doesn’t have that property. Each time git bisect checks
> out a commit, you test if that commit has the property. If it does, mark the commit as
> "new"; otherwise, mark it as "old". When the bisection is done, git bisect will report
> which commit introduced the property.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You can't change the logic of `git bisect`</strike> turns out you actually can, see the other answers, but you can change your own logic. Mark the old bug-introducing commit as `good` and the latest commit as `bad`, and do the bisecting as usual, but instead marking good commits as bad and bad commits as good.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to do this but got it all messed up as my brain lost the correct context of good and bad in the middle. However, I just learned in the manpage that we can term our own good and bad so that works perfectly. I'll add that as an answer for more visibility.